# BeginPaint fails when called from injected dll, even after EndPaint is called in target application

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, gdi

Basically what my title says. I'm trying to inject a dll in a target application in order to display things every time the target application receives a WM_PAINT message. There is the WNDPROC of my target:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_PAINT: 
            BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps); 
            TextOut(ps.hdc, 0, 0, "Hello, Windows!", 15); 
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps); 
        break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the dll I inject:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

WNDPROC wpOrigProc;
HWND target_hwnd = (HWND)0x909E6; // HWND of the window I'm detouring

LRESULT APIENTRY MyWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    LRESULT result = CallWindowProc(wpOrigProc, hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);

    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_PAINT: 
            BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            TextOut(ps.hdc, 0, 50, "That was injected!", 18);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        break;
    }

    return result; 
}

int APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE module, DWORD reason, LPVOID reserved)
{
    HHOOK msgHook;
    FILE* stream;

    switch (reason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        wpOrigProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(target_hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG)MyWndProc);
        break;

    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        SetWindowLong(target_hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG)wpOrigProc); 
        break;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Now, I know the problem comes from BeginPaint because if I use GetDC and ReleaseDC instead, it works. It also works if I don't call CallWindowProc before BeginPaint.

It makes no sense to me as the original WNDPROC calls EndPaint at the end of his WM_PAINT, which means it shouldn't interfere with my injected WM_PAINT... Any idea?

Comment: On a side note, you should use [`SetWindowSubclass()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102.aspx) instead of `SetWindowLongPtr(GWLP_WNDPROC)`. See [safer subclassing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/11/55653.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EndPaint()` validates the window, so the next `BeginPaint()` gets a DC that doesn't have any drawable (invalidated) area. Here's a discussion about [GetDC()/ReleaseDC() vs. BeginPaint()/EndPaint()](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66250/BeginPaint-EndPaint-or-GetDC-ReleaseDC).

Comment: Makes sense. The reason I wanted to use BeginPaint was to get the invalidated part of window from the PAINTSTRUCT. Is that possible without interfering with CallWindowProc and the original WNDPROC of the target process?

Comment: @SoftEngi: You can use `GetUpdateRgn` to get a window's current update region and pass that to `GetDCEx` to mimic the DC you would get from `BeginPaint`.